# Extracting numeric data from lines starting with specific text

Tags: python, regex

I've got the following sample text:

```py
Active Stages - U: 1-18, L: 1-23
Passive Stages - U: 19-23
Attachments provided for stages - U: 1, 14; L: 1
```

I want to extract `U: 1-18` and `L: 1-23` from a line that starts with a specific text. Note that each line contains at least one `U` or `L` group.

For a line that starts with `Passive Stages`, I tried to use a regex with named groups like this:

```py
re.findall('\nPassive Stages.*?U: (?P<upper>\d+(?:-\d+)*?)|L: (?P<lower>\d+(?:-\d+)*?)\n')
```

However,
it is not capturing the line with `Passive Stages` string.

Please advise me how to write a regex for this situation.

Comment: It does not because of the `\n` (and you should use `*` instead of `*?` with `(?:-\d+)`). Do you mean you only need the `U` and `L` values from a line that starts with `Passive Stages`?

Comment: assume, there is no \n
I want to have U, L values from Passive Stages line, not from other lines.

Comment: Will https://ideone.com/10sJYb work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a line that starts with the text you want and then find all matches  of `L` or `U` followed by a colon, whitespaces and then a number or a number range.

Here is a [sample Python demo](https://ideone.com/10sJYb):

```py
import re

text = """Active Stages - U: 1-18, L: 1-23
Passive Stages - U: 19-23
Attachments provided for stages - U: 1, 14; L: 1"""

rx = re.compile(r"\b([UL]):\s*(\d+(?:-\d+)*)")

for line in text.splitlines(False):
    if line.startswith("Passive Stages"):
        match = dict(rx.findall(line))
        print(match)
```

Here,

- `line.startswith("Passive Stages")` checks if the line starts with the required substring
- `\b([UL]):\s*(\d+(?:-\d+)*)` regex matches

  - `\b` - a word boundary
  - `([UL])` - Group 1: `U` or `L`
  - `:\s*` - a colon and then zero or more whitespaces
  - `(\d+(?:-\d+)*)` - Group 2: one or more digits and then zero or more repetitions of a `-` and one or more digits
  - `dict(rx.findall(line))` - collects the matches and creates a dictionary with the found values.